# Using Docker and Dependecy Injection Framewrok

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, docker, integration-testing

I would like to make an integration test of two modules: one is my app that can send email based on some business rule. In the development enviroment i mocked the email proxy, so then`send_email` is mocked.
So i have a factory that builds the real proxy email or just a mock.

When i deploy my app, i would like it to use a real proxy. I will deploy it using a docker container.

What is the best approach?
Can I use a Dependecy injection framework to change the proxy email?

Answer (score 1):

Your factory could generate the right proxy email based on the presence of an environment variable.

Since you can [run your container with an environment variable passed at runtime (`docker run -e env=value`)](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#env-environment-variables), that would help the factory to know what to do.